# iOS - Take all the available space in a horizontal UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, uistackview

I have `UITableViewCell` that contains a horizontal `UIStackView`. The `UIStackView` contains four views in the following order.

```
UIImageView   UILabel    UILabel UIImageView
```

There are `16 points` spacing after the `arrangedSubViews`. I want that the second UILabel takes all the available space. If there is not enough space, it text should wrap.

I have used the following codes. It works almost. The problem is that even though there is enough space between the `UILabel`'s as you see in the screenshot attached, the second `UILabel` breaks. But I want it to break only if there is not enough space.

[image]

---

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "TableViewCell"
    
    private let leadingImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "calendar"))
        view.setConstraints(heightConstant: 25, widthConstant: 25)
        view.tintColor = .text
        return view
    }()
    
    private let leadingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .label
        label.text = "Start Date"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    
    let trailingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Friday, 17 July 2020"
        label.textColor = .label
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }()
    
    let trailingImageView: UIImageView  = {
        let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 12, weight: .light)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down", withConfiguration: configuration)
        let view = UIImageView(image: image)
        return view
    }()
    
    private let superStackView: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.distribution = .fillProportionally
        view.alignment = .center
        view.spacing = 16
        return view
    }()
    
    private  let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpSubviews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
extension TableViewCell {
    private  func setUpSubviews(){
        containerView.addSubview(trailingImageView)
        trailingImageView.alignCenter(centerXAnchor: containerView.centerXAnchor,
                                      centerYAnchor: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(leadingImageView)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(leadingLabel)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(trailingLabel)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(containerView)
        
        let constant = CGFloat(16)
    
        self.addSubview(superStackView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(superStackView)
        superStackView.setConstraints(topAnchor: contentView.topAnchor, leadingAnchor: contentView.leadingAnchor,
                              bottomAnchor: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailingAnchor: contentView.trailingAnchor,
                              topConstant: constant, leadingConstant: constant, bottomConstant: constant, trailingConstant: constant)
        
        
        self.contentView.updateConstraints()
        
    }
}
```

---

How can I fix this issue so that the cell looks like the cells in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close...

First, setting a stack view's Distribution to `Fill Proportionally` is the most misunderstood distribution option, and you don't want to use it here.

Second, it helps greatly when designing to use contrasting backgrounds to make it easy to see what your frames are doing.

Here is your code, modified to get to what appears to be your goal. I don't have your "constraint helpers" so I changed it to standard constraint format. I also added a few comments for some clarification:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "TableViewCell"
    
    private let leadingImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "calendar"))
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        //view.setConstraints(heightConstant: 25, widthConstant: 25)
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        view.tintColor = .blue // .text
        return view
    }()
    
    private let leadingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .label
        label.text = "Start Date"
        // only single line for "leading label"
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        // content hugging
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return label
    }()
    
    let trailingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Friday, 17 July 2020"
        label.textColor = .label
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        return label
    }()
    
    let trailingImageView: UIImageView  = {
        let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 12, weight: .light)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down", withConfiguration: configuration)
        let view = UIImageView(image: image)
        return view
    }()
    
    private let superStackView: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // do NOT use .fillProportionally
        view.distribution = .fill
        view.alignment = .center
        view.spacing = 16
        return view
    }()
    
    private  let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        // not needed
        //view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        //view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpSubviews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
extension TableViewCell {
    private  func setUpSubviews(){
        containerView.addSubview(trailingImageView)
        //trailingImageView.alignCenter(centerXAnchor: containerView.centerXAnchor,
        //                            centerYAnchor: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(leadingImageView)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(leadingLabel)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(trailingLabel)
        superStackView.addArrangedSubview(containerView)
        
        let constant = CGFloat(16)
        
        self.addSubview(superStackView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(superStackView)
        //superStackView.setConstraints(topAnchor: contentView.topAnchor, leadingAnchor: contentView.leadingAnchor,
        //                            bottomAnchor: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailingAnchor: contentView.trailingAnchor,
        //                            topConstant: constant, leadingConstant: constant, bottomConstant: constant, trailingConstant: constant)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            trailingImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
            trailingImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor),
            
            superStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: constant),
            superStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: constant),
            superStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -constant),
            superStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -constant),

        ])

        // not needed
        //self.contentView.updateConstraints()
        
    }
}
```

---

And, an example view controller:

```
class MahanTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = [
        "Saturday, 18 July 2020",
        "Sunday, 19 July 2020",
        "Wednesday, 22 July 2020",
        "Saturday, 26 September 2020",
        "Sunday, 27 September 2020",
        "Wednesday, 30 September 2020",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.trailingLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Producing this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to Return 1

```
let trailingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Friday, 17 July 2020"
        label.textColor = .label
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }()
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I need the text wraps if there is not enough place.

Comment: I do not want to scale down font-size.

Comment: okay ... so what you want if text increase ? what options left ? either font scale or wrape text or multiline ... choose one

Comment: By default, no wrap and one line. Multiline text if there is less then 16 points spacing between the two label.

Comment: check it in view Hierarchy to see whats going on .. can you send demo project to test ?

Comment: sed it via wetransfer.com